# Alternatives for OrientDB Schema

Tags: java, xsd, schema, orientdb

The OrientDB documentation describes how to use their API enabled schema for Java graph databases in ways like the following..

```
profile.createProperty("nick", OType.STRING).setMin("3").setMax("30").setMandatory(true).setNotNull(true);
```

Are there other possible alternatives for creating and enforcing a schema with OrientDB? (i.e. XML, JSON, XSD) Or is their API the only way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do it from OrientDB Studio (web UI) or with simple SQL statements (executed from Studio, console, any programmatic API or from REST protocol http://orientdb.com/docs/last/OrientDB-REST.html), eg.

```
 create class Person extends V
 create property Person.name STRING 
 alter property Person.name MANDATORY true
```

http://orientdb.com/docs/last/SQL-Create-Class.html

http://orientdb.com/docs/last/SQL-Create-Property.html